# Angular - BrowserAnimationsModule animations error

Tags: angular

I´m trying to create fade out/fade in animations between pages in angular.

I create animations.ts with fade

```
import {trigger,animate,transition,style,query} from "@angular/animations";

export const fadeAnimation = trigger("fadeAnimation", [
  transition("* => *", [
    query(":enter", [style({ opacity: 0 })], { optional: true }),
    query(
      ":leave",
      [style({ opacity: 1 }), animate("0.3s", style({ opacity: 0 }))],
      { optional: true }
    ),
    query(
      ":enter",
      [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate("0.3s", style({ opacity: 1 }))],
      { optional: true }
    )
  ])
]);
```

Then in app.module i import BrowserAnimationsModule

```
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AdminModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally i add this add this animations in route

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-admin-header></app-admin-header>
  <app-admin-left-side></app-admin-left-side>
  <main [@fadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
  </main>
  <app-admin-footer></app-admin-footer>
</div>
```

In this last component in console.log return

> Found the synthetic property @fadeAnimation. Please include either
>   "BrowserAnimationsModule"

I think i import animations right so i don´t know where is the error. I use Angular 7. Somebody know where is the error?

**UPDATE**: No works

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fadeAnimation } from './../../../../app/animations.component';

@Component({
  selector   : 'app-usuariosform',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls  : ['./form.component.css'],
  animations : [fadeAnimation]
})
```

Comment: Make sure that BrowserModule goes first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

```
animations: [ fadeAnimation ]
```

on your @Component ts file.

Comment: Make sure the @angular/animations package is installed (e.g. by running npm install @angular/animations

Comment: Same error. In the console.log the error appears when try to do this <main [@fadeAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
 </main>

Comment: seems the problem is you are having the animation in some other component too

Comment: how can we pass arguments using this syntax

Answer (score 0):

Please see this page, [https://angular.io/guide/animations](http://%20https://angular.io/guide/animations)

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-open-close',
  animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      // ...
      state('open', style({
        height: '200px',
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      })),
      state('closed', style({
        height: '100px',
        opacity: 0.5,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      })),
      transition('open => closed', [
        animate('1s')
      ]),
      transition('closed => open', [
        animate('0.5s')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
  templateUrl: 'open-close.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['open-close.component.css']
})
export class OpenCloseComponent {
  isOpen = true;

  toggle() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" class="open-close-container">
  <p>The box is now {{ isOpen ? 'Open' : 'Closed' }}!</p>
</div>
```

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/animations#code-review) you can see code review. Hope it help.